# 'RequestError: Error: Invalid URI' when uploading file to parse server cloud

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I am using this sample code from the parse javascript sdk in main.js of my electron app, it works fine with the example URI, but when i use my own URI, which is to a local file at the route level of my app, I get the following RequestError message,

> Error: Invalid URI.

The URI i am trying to use is 
`file://${__dirname}/tempInv.pdf`
I have tried every different variation of the file's address I can think of, but still the same result. Is there some way of point to localhost maybe that would get past this error. The app will be deployed so needs to work across platforms.

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const Parse = require('parse/node');

....

const options = {
  uri: 'https://-----/-----',
  resolveWithFullResponse: true,
  encoding: null, // <-- this is important for binary data like images.
};

request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    const data = Array.from(Buffer.from(response.body, 'binary'));
    const contentType = response.headers['content-type'];
    const file = new Parse.File('logo', data, contentType);
    return file.save();
  })
  .then((file => console.log(file.url())))
  .catch(console.error);
```

```
const Parse = require('parse/node');

const express = require('express');
const XeroClient = require('xero-node').AccountingAPIClient;
const config = require('./config.json');

const fs  = require('fs');

const request = require('request-promise');

let appEx = express();

let lastRequestToken = null;
let xeroClient = new XeroClient(config);


appEx.set('port', 3000)

ipcMain.on('message-createInvoice', function (event, data) {

    let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 340, height: 480 });
        win.setPosition(0, 0);
        win.loadURL('http://localhost:3000/');

    appEx.get('/', async function(req, res) {

        lastRequestToken = await xeroClient.oauth1Client.getRequestToken();
        let authoriseUrl = xeroClient.oauth1Client.buildAuthoriseUrl(lastRequestToken);

        res.redirect(authoriseUrl);

    })   


    appEx.get('/callback', async function(req, res) {

        let oauth_verifier = req.query.oauth_verifier;
        let accessToken = await xeroClient.oauth1Client.swapRequestTokenforAccessToken(lastRequestToken, oauth_verifier)
            .then(async() => {
                var invoice = await xeroClient.invoices.create(data)           
                    .then((invoice) => {
                        var inv = invoice["Invoices"][0];
                        var invId = inv["InvoiceID"];

                        xeroClient.invoices.savePDF({ InvoiceID: invId, savePath: path.join(__dirname, '../temp-files/temp-inv.pdf',)})
                            .then(() => {

                                Parse.initialize("--appId--");    
                                Parse.serverURL = 'http://--.---.--.---:80/parse';

                                const data = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../temp-files/temp-inv.pdf'));

                                const file = await new Parse.File('inv.pdf', [...data]);
                                return file.save()
                                    .then((file) => {
                                        var Invoices = Parse.Object.extend("Invoices");
                                        var invoice = new Invoices;
                                        invoice.set('invPdf', file);
                                        invoice.save();     
                                        event.returnValue = true;
                                        win.close();
                                    })
                                    .catch((err) => {
                                    console.log('Failed to save invoice to Parse Cloud: ' + err);
                                    event.returnValue = false;
                                    win.close();
                                    })

                            })
                            .catch((err) => {
                            console.log('Failed to save invoice to temp-file: ' + err);
                            event.returnValue = false;
                            win.close();
                            })
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                    console.log('Failed to create invoice in xero' + err);
                    event.returnValue = false;
                    win.close();
                    })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('Oauth failed' + err);
                event.returnValue = false;
                win.close();
            })
    })

    event.sender.send('message-createInvoice', true);

});


appEx.listen(appEx.get('port'), function() {
    console.log("Your Xero basic public app is running at http://localhost:" + appEx.get('port'))
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `request-promise` is not the best way to read a local file. I recommend you to use `fs` package. It would be something like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const Parse = require('parse/node');

....

const data = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './tempInv.pdf'));
const file = new Parse.File('logo.pdf', [...data]);
file.save()
  .then(file => console.log(file.url()))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Hi Davi,

This is giving an error.

`Cannot create a Parse.File with that data`

Is this something to do with contentType not being set or maybe an encoding issue?

Comment: I've just edited the result. Basically changed this line: `const file = new Parse.File('logo.pdf', [...data]);` Can you please try again?

Comment: Thanks Davi, so does this turn it into an array?

Comment: Yes. `fs.readFileSync()` returns a buffer and `[...data]` converts this buffer to an Array, which is what `new Parse.File()` expects. Don't forget to add the extension in the file name as in my example `logo.pdf` so Parse Server can automatically handle the file type. I tested this code and it is working fine for me.

Comment: Im now getting an error with this   
`ParseError: 100 XMLHttpRequest failed: "Unable to connect to the Parse API"`
I dont what has caused this, parse queries are working as normal, but I can no longer access the cloud with the above code.

Comment: Have you [initialized](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#getting-started) the Parse SDK?

Comment: yep, the same way as elsewhere in my app.
`Parse.initialize("appId");    
 Parse.serverURL = 'http://--.---.---.--:--/parse';`

only fails to work with parse cloud. IE Parse.File  -- file.save

Comment: What is really odd about this is that it was working fine before and i havent changed the index.js code.

Comment: Don't you have a javascript key? If so, you need to initialize with `Parse.initialize("appId", "javascript");` I tested this code I sent you and I'm pretty sure it works. You may be doing something wrong in your code. If you can edit the question with the complete version of your current code I can try to help. If possible, also share how you are initializing Parse Server.

Comment: Hi Davi, I wasnt given a javascriptId, initialise has always worked without it, also this worked perfectly when I first used your code, but has stopped now. I have managed a work around by passing the data back to the renderer process and then saving the Parse.File to the cloud and then adding to my parse server. I still don't understand why this works in the renderer, but not in the main.js. Maybe its something to do with the code being in an express app on port 3000.

Comment: Maybe... I'd need to see the complete code to help figure it out.

Comment: whats the best way to add it here??

Comment: You can edit your question and update the code there.

Comment: I have added the code above to the original question

Comment: What's the error that you have now and which line is throwing the error?

Comment: The error comes on the final function. 'Failed to save invoice to Parse Cloud: '. the error is `ParseError: 100 XMLHttpRequest failed: "Unable to connect to the Parse API"` everything else works fine. Also same code works fine from the renderer.js.

Comment: can you please fix `var invoice = new Invoices;` to `var invoice = new Invoices();` and double check if the url that you are setting in `Parse.serverURL = 'http://--.---.--.---:80/parse';` is right?

Comment: `var invoice = new Invoices();` seems to have worked. Which is odd because I have made that same error in my code outside of the main.js but it hadn't caused a problem, which is odd.